# other XML snippet getting trimmed while replacing attribute values via shell script and Control Interaction via shell loop

Tags: linux, shell

While replacing the value of RC attribute with random number, other xml snippets getting trimmed
I)Can you guys provide the solution and cause?
II)Can you please provide your solution on how control the interaction to replace the value of RC attribute for specific range?
Ex: I want to replace based on user inputs
Say, User Enter 3 and 3 RC attribute should only get replaced with random in output

Please refer xml file: test.xml  and my actual output, command used and expected output
test.xml

```
<documents><document id ="test"><doc:meta title = 'test-title'><doc-transform><item name="RC" value="1445352777130287"></item><item name="VERSION" value="05-07-0044"></item><item name="DATE" value="2021-08-25"></item></doc-transform></doc:meta></document><document id ="test-2"><doc:meta title = 'test-title-2'><doc-transform><item name="RC" value="3527771302"></item><item name="VERSION" value="05-07-0044"></item><item name="DATE" value="2021-08-25"></item></doc-transform></doc:meta></document></documents>
```

Command Used:

var2=$RANDOM

sed -E -i 's|(item name="RC" value=").*(">)|\1'$var2'\2|' test.xml

Getting below output:

```
<documents><document id ="test"><doc:meta title = 'test-title'><doc-transform><item name="RC" value="23207"></item></doc-transform></doc:meta></document></documents>
```

Expected Output:
only value of RC attributes should get changed and it shouldn't affect other xml snippets

```
<documents><document id ="test"><doc:meta title = 'test-title'><doc-transform><item name="RC" value="78788"></item><item name="VERSION" value="05-07-0044"></item><item name="DATE" value="2021-08-25"></item></doc-transform></doc:meta></document><document id ="test-2"><doc:meta title = 'test-title-2'><doc-transform><item name="RC" value="78788"></item><item name="VERSION" value="05-07-0044"></item><item name="DATE" value="2021-08-25"></item></doc-transform></doc:meta></document></documents>
```

Comment: Use `xmlstarlet` or another tool that natively understands xml, not `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the greedy regex you are using `.*`. You can debug your example putting this greedy regex in a group and printing the content, example:

```
sed -E 's|(item name="RC" value=")(.*)(">)|\1\n\2\n\3|' test.xml|nl
```

output:

```
1   <documents><document id ="test"><doc:meta title = 'test-title'><doc-transform><item name="RC" value="
2   1445352777130287"></item><item name="VERSION" value="05-07-0044"></item><item name="DATE" value="2021-08-25"></item></doc-transform></doc:meta></document><document id ="test-2"><doc:meta title = 'test-title-2'><doc-transform><item name="RC" value="3527771302"></item><item name="VERSION" value="05-07-0044"></item><item name="DATE" value="2021-08-25
3   "></item></doc-transform></doc:meta></document></documents>
```

Line 2 is the match of the greedy regex.

To solve this problem you need to restringe the match, like:

```
sed -E 's|(item name="RC" value=")[^"]*(">)|\1###########\2|' test.xml
```

output:

```
<documents><document id ="test"><doc:meta title = 'test-title'><doc-transform><item name="RC" value="###########"></item><item name="VERSION" value="05-07-0044"></item><item name="DATE" value="2021-08-25"></item></doc-transform></doc:meta></document><document id ="test-2"><doc:meta title = 'test-title-2'><doc-transform><item name="RC" value="3527771302"></item><item name="VERSION" value="05-07-0044"></item><item name="DATE" value="2021-08-25"></item></doc-transform></doc:meta></document></documents>
```

But as already mentioned, sed is not a good tool to work with html/xml. sed will work only if your input is always like your input example.

Comment: Thank you ❤️, @Ronaldo Is it possible to replace only three occurance s? I tried like this, but it replacing 3rd occurance not 
 first three
sed -E 's|(item name="RC" value=")[^"]*(">)|\1###########\2|3' test.xml

Comment: You can just repeat the sed commands 3 times or, inside the same inline script, repeat the `s/` commands separated by ";". You can also control interactions through a shell loop.

Comment: Thanks @Ronaldo  Can you please suggest  how we can control interaction through shell loop?

Comment: Your new needs don't match your original question. It's better update.

Comment: Updated the original question and description Can you please suggest? I tried replacing 'g' with user input value in above sed command  not working
sed -E 's|(item name="RC" value=")[^"]*(">)|\1###########\2|g' test.xml

Comment: i have created new question,
you can find here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69014615/replace-xml-attribute-values-for-specific-range-in-shell-script