# Replace xml attribute values for specific range in Shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have below `test.xml` file and I want to replace the attribute `value` for a specific range.

I want to replace the number of `RC` `value` with a random number, based on user input.

For example: if the user wants to replace only the first three `RC` `value` then it should update the first three `RC` `value`.

The `test.xml` content is as follows:

```xml
<documents><document id ="test"><doc:meta title = 'test-title'><doc-transform><item name="RC" value="1445352777130287"></item><item name="VERSION" value="05-07-0044"></item><item name="DATE" value="2021-08-25"></item></doc-transform></doc:meta></document><document id ="test-2"><doc:meta title = 'test-title-2'><doc-transform><item name="RC" value="3527771302"></item><item name="VERSION" value="05-07-0044"></item><item name="DATE" value="2021-08-25"></item></doc-transform></doc:meta></document></documents>
```

I have tried the below code in a shell script, but it is still replacing all `RC` attribute `value`:

```sh
var=$1 #Command line arguments
var2=$RANDOM
for i in $1;
do
sed -E -i 's|(item name="RC" value=").*(">)|\1'$var2'\2|' test.xml
done
```

I have tried another code in the shell script, but it is still replacing all `RC` attribute `value`:

```sh
var=$1 #Command line arguments
var2=$RANDOM
for i in $1;
do
sed -E -i 's|(item name="RC" value=").*(">)|\1'$var2'\2|$var' test.xml
done
```

Can you please suggest a solution for this?

If iterating over interaction mode is possible can you guys suggest me?

Comment: Use a real XML parser to process XML.  There are too many ways that XML processing can go wrong, otherwise.  For something like this, I'd go further to suggest using an XSLT processor (which necessarily incorporates an XML parser).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, a tool that understands XML is the way to go. Regular expressions are almost always the wrong thing to use when it comes to XML (There are lots of questions and answers about why on SO if you do some searching); XPath is much better for describing what you want to match.

Example using `xmlstarlet` to update a user-supplied number of values to random numbers:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

random_rcs() {
    local count="$1" filename="$2" n
    local -a args
    for (( n = 0; n < count; n++ )); do
        args+=(--update "(//item[@name=\"RC\"])[$n]/@value" -v $RANDOM)
    done
    xmlstarlet ed --inplace "${args[@]}" "$filename"
}

random_rcs 3 test.xml
```

It builds an array of arguments to `xmlstarlet ed`, each one of which changes the value attribute of a node matching a XPath expression to find the n-th item node with a name attribute of `"RC"`.

Your sample XML produces some warnings about namespaces; if your real input does too, fix the file or redirect standard error to `/dev/null`. (If using namespaces, the XPath expressions might need some tweaking too.)

Comment: Thank you Shwan, is it possible to use the sed? I am restricted to use xmlstarlet

Comment: @KAS That would be like trying to use a hammer to cut a 2x4 to size. Wrong tool for the job entirely.